How do I pass a table's name as a parameter in MyAccess?
 query.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO :table VALUES (ID = 2, Name = ''John'', Value = 1.1);';
 query.ParamByName('table').AsString := 'testtable';

This leads to the table's name being put in quotes, thus breaking MySQL syntax. This makes sense, but it means I have no idea of how to actually have the table name as a parameter.
Thanks !

You can't. Only column values are allowed as parameters. Table and column names are not supported. (BTW, it makes no sense to try to parameterize a table name when you're concatenating string values into the columns.)
You can work around this by using the format function before setting parameter values:
var
  SQLText: string;
begin
  qry.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO %s VALUES (ID = 2, Name = :FirstName, Value = :Value);';
  qry.SQL.Text := Format(SQLText, ['TableName']);
  qry.ParamByName('FirstName').AsString := 'John';
  qry.ParamByName('Value').AsFloat := 1.1;
end;


Just be careful to sanitize the table name if it comes from user input. Any time you have to build an SQL string by hand, you risk an injection attack

use MacroByName
https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Athens/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC)
query.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO &table VALUES (ID = 2, Name = ''John'', Value = 1.1);';
query.MacroByName('table').AsIdentifier := 'testtable';


Maybe add that this is firedac specific, OP is using mydac so it may not apply to them.

If you are building your SQL by hand, my suggestion is you could use a variable and concat it into the SQL text.
tname:= 'table1';
sSql:= 'Insert into '+tname+'(ID,Name,Value) ';
sSql:= sSql + 'VALUES (2,"John",1.1)';
Query1.SQL.Text:= sSql;

Of course, tname and sSql are String variables.
